# angular material TimePicker ngx-material-timepicker Error Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Tags: angular, angular-material, timepicker

I use ngx-material-timepicker timePicker install from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-material-timepicker)
with command `npm install --save ngx-material-timepicker`
also i install dependencies luxon and tslib 
and according to npm

```
   import {NgxMaterialTimepickerModule} from 'ngx-material-timepicker';
    @NgModule({
      imports: [NgxMaterialTimepickerModule]
    })
```

and in my html file

```
<input [ngxTimepicker]="picker">
<ngx-material-timepicker #picker></ngx-material-timepicker>
```

but error

```
core.js:15724 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at ngx-material-timepicker.js:231
    at Module../node_modules/ngx-material-timepicker/fesm5/ngx-material-timepicker.js (ngx-material-timepicker.js:238)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:83)
    at Module../src/app/modules/management/admin/admin.module.ts (admin-routing.module.ts:145)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:83)
    at $_lazy_route_resource lazy namespace object:34
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:391)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:17299)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:390)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (zone.js:150)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:831)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:788)
    at zone.js:892
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:17290)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:601)
```

Comment: which version of ngx-material-timepicker did you install?

Comment: last version is 4.0.1
and i think when run npm install --save ngx-material-timepicker  automatically install last version

Comment: Which version of Angular?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

based on github [issue](https://github.com/Agranom/ngx-material-timepicker/issues/173) and [this](https://github.com/Agranom/ngx-material-timepicker/issues/158) you can use version 3.3.1 of "ngx-material-timepicker" or if you are using angular 8 you can use version v4.0.0 or go to `/node_modules/ngx-material-timepicker/fesm5/ngx-material-timepicker.js` and change the `ɵɵdefineInjectable` to `defineInjectable`.

Comment: i use angular 7.3.7 and so install timepicker version 3 and  is ok  tank a lot

Comment: Is it really a sane idea to edit something in the node modules??

Comment: Thank you so much, wasted so much time for this.

Comment: Which version of "ngx-material-timepicker" to use if I am using Angular 10?